# MongoDB incremental mapReduce, select only new documents, added after last mapReduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Let's say I have a collection with documents that looks like this (just simplified example, but it should show the scheme):

```
> db.data.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c1f27aa3dd60ee98282cf"), "type" : "A", "value" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c1f33aa3dd60ee98282d0"), "type" : "A", "value" : 58 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c1f40aa3dd60ee98282d1"), "type" : "B", "value" : 37 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c1f50aa3dd60ee98282d2"), "type" : "B", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c1f56aa3dd60ee98282d3"), "type" : "A", "value" : 85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c1f5daa3dd60ee98282d4"), "type" : "B", "value" : 12 }
```

Now I need to collect some statistics on that collection. For example:

```
db.data.mapReduce(function(){
        emit(this.type,this.value);
     },function(key,values){
        var total = 0;
        for(i in values) {total+=values[i]};
        return total;
     },
{out:'stat'})
```

will collect totals in 'stat' collection.

```
> db.stat.find()
{ "_id" : "A", "value" : 154 }
{ "_id" : "B", "value" : 50 }
```

At this point everything is perfect, but I've stuck on the next move:

1. 'data' collection is constantly updated with new data (old documents stays unchanged, only inserts, no updates)
2. I would like to periodically update 'stat' collection, but do not want to query the whole 'data' collection every time, so I choose to run incremental mapReduce
3. It may seems good to just update 'stat' collection on every insert in 'data' collection and do no use mapReduce, but the real case is more complex than this example and I would like to get statistics only on demand.
4. To do this I should be able to query only documents, that was added after my last mapReduce
5. As far as I understand I cannot rely on ObjectId property, just store the last one and later select every document with ObjectId > stored because ObjectId is not equal autoincrement ids in SQL databases (for example different shards will produce different ObjectIds).
6. I can change ObjectId generator, but not sure how to do it better in sharded environment

So the question is:

Is it any way to select only documents, added after the last mapReduce to run incremental mapReduce or may be there is another strategy to update statistic data on constantly growing collection?

Comment: I just thought that I can use skip() to solve that, need to check on the real case. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cache the time and use it as a barrier for your next incremental map-reduce.

We're testing this at work and it seems to be working.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can't safely do map-reduce while an insert is happening across shards.  The versions become inconsistent and your map-reduce operation will fail.  (If you find a solution to this, please do let me know! :)

We use bulk-inserts instead, once every 5 minutes.  Once all the bulk inserts are done, we run the map-reduce like this (in Python):

```
m = Code(<map function>)
r = Code(<reduce function>)

# pseudo code
end = last_time + 5 minutes

# Use time and optionally any other keys you need here
q = bson.SON([("date" : {"$gte" : last_time, "$lt" : end})])

collection.map_reduce(m, r, out=out={"reduce": <output_collection>}, query=q)
```

Note that we used `reduce` and not `merge`, because we don't want to override what we had before; we want to combine the old results and the new result with the same reduce function.

Answer (score 4):

You can get just the time portion of the ID using `_id.getTime()` (from: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html).  That should be sortable across all shards.

EDIT: Sorry, that was the java docs...  The JS version appears to be _id.generation_time.in_time_zone(Time.zone), from http://mongotips.com/b/a-few-objectid-tricks/

Comment: Thanks for answering! The main problem is that I can get several inserts in the same millisecond (at least I think so if it's even possible - mongodb is pretty fast and it could happens on the different shards) and there is a chance that some of documents will be missed or counted twice. Or am I being too worried about that? :)

Comment: Try to structure the analysis function so that if you end up processing a row twice nothing bad happens- just done extra work.  Then you can use the timestamp of the objectID to avoid reprocessing the whole collection- if you end up reprocessing a row or two here or there it isn't a big deal.

Comment: Use the merge output option for MR to merge the output by key.  From http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce: { merge : "collectionName" } - This option will merge new data into the old output collection. In other words, if the same key exists in both the result set and the old collection, the new key will overwrite the old one.

Comment: hm... I did mean { merge : "collectionName" } for "incremental mapReduce", but I don't see now how I can structure the analysis with the scheme as above so processing some documents twice will not mess gathered data.

Comment: How about bucketing them not just by type, but by type/year/month/day/hour?  Then you can just requery the last 2 hours worth of data.  If that's too much, break it down to the minute.  MongoDB is good for that, since you can still make your key "_id", but then have child nodes for each year/day/hour/etc, and if you want fully aggregate sums at the top level, you can very quickly recompute from the time-bucketed aggregates.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up a complete pymongo-based solution that uses incremental map-reduce and caches the time, and expects to run in a cron job.  It locks itself so two can't run concurrently:

https://gist.github.com/2233072

```
""" This method performs an incremental map-reduce on any new data in 'source_table_name' 
into 'target_table_name'.  It can be run in a cron job, for instance, and on each execution will
process only the new, unprocessed records.  

The set of data to be processed incrementally is determined non-invasively (meaning the source table is not 
written to) by using the queued_date field 'source_queued_date_field_name'. When a record is ready to be processed, 
simply set its queued_date (which should be indexed for efficiency). When incremental_map_reduce() is run, any documents 
with queued_dates between the counter in 'counter_key' and 'max_datetime' will be map/reduced.

If reset is True, it will drop 'target_table_name' before starting.

If max_datetime is given, it will only process records up to that date.

If limit_items is given, it will only process (roughly) that many items. If multiple
items share the same date stamp (as specified in 'source_queued_date_field_name') then
it has to fetch all of those or it'll lose track, so it includes them all. 

If unspecified/None, counter_key defaults to counter_table_name:LastMaxDatetime.
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

We solve this issue using 'normalized' ObjectIds. Steps that we are doing:

1. normalize id - take timestap from the current/stored/last processed id and set other
   parts of id to its min values. C# code: `new ObjectId(objectId.Timestamp,
   0, short.MinValue, 0)`
2. run map-reduce with all items that have id
   greater than our normalized id, skip already processed items.
3. store last processed id, and mark all processed items.

Note: Some boundary items will be processed several times. To fix it we set some sort of a flag in the processed items.